# XSSFWorkbook is taking too much time to load excel file using InputStream

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssfworkbook

When I'm trying to read Excel file using Apache PO XSSFWorkbook, below line is taking more than 20 minutes for loading a 4 MB Excel file.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(blob.getBinaryStream());
```

I tried with workbook.create() streaming method as well, but result is the same. Kindly suggest and advise on below issue

I tried all the possible approaches of Excel file read like SXSSFWorkbook, Workbook, XSSFReader), but not getting fruitful results. My expectation is program should read file as fast as possible.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the logging as per the FAQ on POI https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10109

Comment: Hi @ARK, even after disabling the logging option the result is same.

Comment: Is it possible to try the constructor that takes the file instead of the input stream? as per this post https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream

Comment: Are you loading the excel data from a database blob?

Comment: Yes I'm loading blob data from the DB, I print the blob length as well just above this statement, it's able to print very quickly.